# how to change image/interface on first time the computer is turned on?

Tags: boot, bios

I have no idea what's name of this, but it's like a "BIOS splash image"? or what else.
I mean that when you turn on the computer and display screen at the first time where we can get into the BIOS settings by pressing any key on the keyboard.
we know that every computer brand has a different look for this.
so anybody know how to change it? is it possible?

Comment: It depends on motherboard manufacturer, I know that gigabyte has this utility. What is your mb manufacturer and model?

Comment: @miky Manufacturer:Acer ; Model:Aspire 4730Z(uPGA-478)

Comment: I believe that changing bios splash image isnt often possible on notebooks, but I can be wrong. Anyway, try to search app for this on cd with drivers or on the manufacturer support page for your model. There is no universal app for this, so I cant tell you exact name.

Comment: I just update my BIOS driver from the official Acer directory sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the Acer Aspire line has AMI Bios. You mentioned you already updated your BIOS so you should still have this update file. Basically to change the bios oem splash screen you can modify the image that is embedded in the BIOS update. For AMI, there is a tool called ChangeLogo which you'll have to download and use. Please note that there are two versions of the tool, one for UEFI BIOS and one for legacy BIOS.

Apparently, Intel has a link to [just such a tool](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?lang=eng&changeLang=true&DwnldID=11027) but not sure if it does any other special checking for intel stuff.

The official one from AMI (UEFI version) is called AMI Aptio Change Logo 4.52.0.37 but you'll have to find a copy on your own...

The older version (non-UEFI) from an unofficial source is available [here](ftp://ftp.qualitech.net/Intel/Motherboard/S3000AH/ChangeLogo/)

Lastly, I'd like to mention that you run a large risk when flashing a modified BIOS to your machine. If there are any problems with the update, your device may become bricked and you'll just have an expensive paperweight.

Comment: this maybe the way that has helped, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**It may be  possible** : I don't know if your specific device supports them , but BIOS modders are known to do that.But , it often involves modifying  the BIOS modules and flashing the modified BIOS modules to  ROM BIOS , which is always a risky adventure.If you are lucky ,you may end up with a bricked device.

Unless you badly want to replace the BIOS splash screen , don't proceed with the idea.This [link](http://donovan6000.blogspot.fr/2013/06/insyde-bios-modding-splash-screen-logo.html) might give you a slight idea into what this *(modifying BIOS modules and flashing them)* might look like.

**update**:

This [link](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/How-to-Perform-a-BIOS-Upgrade/33/1) may be helpful in understanding the BIOS update procedure.

Comment: like you're saying, that ROM can programmable back. is there a tool that can be used to instantly modify?

Comment: yeah , there are windows BIOS programmers / DOS BIOS programmers.PLZ read the article at the link in update session.one such tool is winflash.